# Are there any better English translations of Solaris available, beyond the original translation from French?

Tags: translation, stanislaw-lem

The version of [*Solaris*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solaris_%28novel%29) that I've read, apparently been translated into English from French, was never considered to be particularly good by Stanisław Lem. Have any other translation attempts been made, which are generally considered to be better?

Comment: [This old thread](http://groups.google.com/group/rec.arts.sf.written/browse_frm/thread/9558e7643b11947f/d22a4bbc879531db) suggests not, but I don't have a definitive answer.

Comment: Extremely subjective; "better" can't really be answered without resorting to opinion.

Comment: @neilfein: "better" -> "more faithful"?

Comment: @neilfein, Stuard - "better" by any reasonable measure. There are plenty of ones that would work.

Comment: Your Wikipedia link suggests there have been no other translations, better or worse, and may never be so long as the book stays in copyright and the Polish publishers refuse permission.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A new translation just came out: http://io9.com/5812648/solaris-gets-a-new-more-accurate-translation
Some important changes are that names are fixed: Kris Kelvin's wife becomes Harey instead of Rheya; Alpha in Aquarius is Alpha Aquarii.

Answer (score 13):

No, there is no other official English translation. See the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solaris_%28novel%29#English_translation), [Lem's website](http://www.lem.pl/english/faq#Klevin). But, a [new English translation has been made](http://english.lem.pl/works/novels/solaris/196-a-new-translation-of-solaris). It will be avaliabe as an e-book, and an audio book, in the second half of 2011. A print copy would depend on the current rights holders.

Comment: Fantastic, @Pearsonartphoto. Took long enough, but in the end our community site one!

Comment: Gotta go with blueberry fields, I grew up in NB and have to say that most books (at least English and French) change during translation. I'll post some Asterix examples shortly